# Enviar valores de formulario mediante Jquery y retornar respuesta

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, mysql

Ante todo un cordial saludo! Tengo uno formularios en donde el usuario introduce una serie de valores numéricos. Lo que quiero hacer es enviar estos valores a un archivo **PHP** usando Jquery para que el **PHP** me realice una serie de cálculos con estos (resta, multiplcación y division) y me retorne los resultados a la página donde me encuentro y se muestren en una tabla de resultados.

¿Como funciona? Cada formulario cuenta con un botón de envío, el cual pasará los datos al archivo **PHP** usando Jquery para ello y que se ejecute la operación que ya he mencionado, es decir, el usuario puede hacer un envío de varios formularios, cada uno con diferentes valores, y la idea es que cada uno se vaya procesando por separado en el **PHP** y los resultados devueltos se vayan mostrando uno debajo del otro en una tabla para luego enviar estos datos por correo electrónico. Sin más que agregar les mostraré los fragmentos importantes de código esperando que me puedan ayudar:

**FORMULARIOS:**

```html
<tr>
<form id="form_calcular<?php echo $a;?>" name="form_calcular<?php echo $a;?>" method="post">

<td><input type="number" name="cod" id="cod" value="<?php echo $row['cod'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="text" name="producto" id="producto" value="<?php echo $row['producto'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="costo" id="costo" value="<?php echo $row['costo'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="sn_iva" id="sn_iva" value="<?php echo $row['sn_iva'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
 <td><input type="number" name="iva" id="iva" value="<?php echo $row['iva'];?>" class="form-control"></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="pvp" id="pvp" value="<?php echo $row['pvp'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="benef" id="benef" value="<?php echo $row['benef'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="g_med" id="g_med" value="<?php echo $row['g_med'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="ing_comp" id="ing_comp" value="<?php echo $row['ing_comp'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="hc" id="hc" value="<?php echo $row['hc'];?>" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      
<td><input type="number" name="cant" id="cant" value="<?php echo $row['cant'];?>" class="form-control"></td>
      
<td><button type="button" id="calcular" name="calcular" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button></td>
      
</form>
</tr>
```

Como pueden observar, sólo hay 2 campos editables por el usuario mientras que los otros son valores que extraigo de la BD y no son modificables **(En esta tabla)**, la idea es que usuario introduzca el margen de descuento **(Sip, debe ser así jeje)** y la cantidad del producto, entonces envío estos valores al codígo **PHP** y realizo unas formulas para calcular el **PVP SIN IVA**, **COSTO, ETC** y mostrar ya los resultados finales en la segunta tabla que sería la de resultados, lo que intento es simular algo así como funcionan las fórmulas de Excel que al introducir los valores del **DESCUENTO** y **CANTIDAD** lo demás se calcula sólo, pero en este caso se calcularían al pulsar el botón respectivo a cada formulario.

**CÓDIGO JQUERY QUE ENVÍA EL FORMULARIO AL ARCHIVO PHP**

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#calcular").click(function()
{
 var url = "php/calcular_valores.php";
 $.ajax
 ({
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 data: $("#form_calcular<?php echo $a;?>").serialize(),
 beforeSend: function()
{
    $('#imagen-espere').show();
    $('#msj').html('Calculando...');
    $('#msj3').html('');
    $('#msj2').html('');
},
    success:function(respuesta)
{
    $('#imagen-espere').hide();
    if (respuesta==1)
{
    $('#msj3').html('¡No pueden haber valores vacíos!');
    $('#msj').html('');
}
 else if (respuesta==2)
{
/* AQUI NECESITO SABER COMO EXTRAER LOS RESULTADOS DE LAS OPERACIONES PARA MOSTRARLOS EN LA TABLA DESTINO */
}                            
    else if (respuesta==3)
{
    $('#msj3').html('¡Oh! Ha ocurrido un error al procesar su solicitud');
    $('#msj').html('');
}
}
});
 return false;
});
});
```

En este código anterior quisiera que me ayudaran a saber como puedo extraer los resultados de los calculos que me ha realizado el PHP para mostrarlos en la tabla destino (Lo ideal creo que sería devolverlos en un array para armarla tabla, no se que me sugieran ustedes) y bueno, no llevo mucho tiempo usando Jquery así que les agradecería muchiiisimo su ayuda ;-) hasta ahora he logrado implementarlo perfectamente para hacer operaciones de un **CRUD**, pero en este caso aún como que si no see jeje

**ESTE SERÍA EL PHP QUE ME EJECUTE LAS OPERACIONES:**

```html
<?php 

include('conexion.php');

sleep(2);


 $cod = $_POST['cod'];
 $producto = $_POST['producto'];
 $costo = $_POST['costo'];
 $sn_iva = $_POST['sn_iva'];
 $iva = $_POST['iva'];
 $pvp = $_POST['pvp'];
 $benef = $_POST['benef'];
 $g_med = $_POST['g_med'];
 $ing_comp = $_POST['ing_comp'];
 $hc = $_POST['hc'];
 $cant = $_POST['cant'];

 if ($cod =='' or $producto =='' or $costo =='' or $sn_iva =='' or $iva =='' or $pvp =='' or $benef =='' or $g_med =='' or $ing_comp =='' or $hc =='' or $cant =='')
{
echo 1;
}
else
{

$res_sin_iva = $pvp/1.21;
$res_iva = $pvp-$res_sin_iva;
$res_benef = $pvp-$res_iva-$costo;
$res_g_med = $res_benef*42/100+$res_iva;
$res_ing_comp = $res_benef*58/100;

$resultados = "$cod, $producto, $costo, $res_sin_iva, $res_iva, $pvp, $res_benef, $res_g_med, $res_ing_comp, $hc, $cant";
 
echo 2;

}

}
else
{
echo 3;
}
?>
```

Como pueden ver, hay operaciones que dependen de resultados anteriores, como por ejemplo: `$res_iva = $pvp-$res_sin_iva;` que depende del resultado de **"$res_sin_iva"** el cual se lo restamos al valor de **"PVP"**, yo lo veo desde el punto como lo he codificado, donde asigno el resultado de una operación a una variable para luego manipularla con operaciones siguientes

**PD: Si me sugieren una mejor manera de lograr este funcionamiento con gusto soy todo oídos**

Comment: Sólo una aclaración, ninguno de tus `input` tiene la propiedad `name`. Desde `PHP` cuando hacés `$cod = $_POST['cod'];` le estás indicando que levante el valor del `<input name="cod">`. Agregale el nombre correspondiente a cada uno.

Comment: Ahh si correcto, es que los tenía de otra manera porque primero había intentado trabajarlo de otra manera y o me funcionó entonces ahora estoy intentando así y no me percate de que había borrado eso jeje muchas gracias por la observación (y)